# React native - executing store method via action while retaining `this` context of component

Tags: action, this, store, react-native

Hopefully this code sample does a good job of explaining the problem that I am trying to solve.

```
/**
 * We happen to be working in React Native here, so fluxible's 
 * connectToStores as well as the implementation of flux-react
 * are non-starters here due to both's peer dependency on
 * react.
 */

// Store.js
var Store = {
  getState: function () {
    var endpoint = '/endpoint';

    var promise = fetch(endpoint)
      .then(response => response.json());

    return Promise.resolve(promise)
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({
          hasData: true,
          data: data
        });
      })
      .done();
  }
};

module.exports = Store;

// Component.js
var Component = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      hasData: false,
      data: {}
    };
  },

  componentDidUpdate: function () {
    console.log('this.state', this.state);
  },

  componentDidMount: function () {
    /**
     * Rather than directly apply here, possible to wrap the Store somehow
     * so that the Component scope of `this` is applied automatically when
     * calling _any_ of Store's methods?
     *
     * Even better, how to execute an action here that triggers a method in
     * the Store and passes along `this` from the Component as the context.
     */
    Store.getState.apply(this);
  },

  render: function () {
    return (
      <View></View>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = Component;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did with passing the 'this' should work. However, I would suggest doing something like:

```
this.setState(Store.getState())
```

If you are repeating this multiple times, you can use a mixin. In a mixin, your 'this' is the context.

Comment: Right, the code I have does work just fine. I am striving for something more elegant. As far as I know, I have to operate directly on state from within the store, as I don't believe I can return a value from within the resolved Promise in  `getState()` other than another Promise.

Comment: Also, note that I am working towards a future without mixins since the general consensus is that we will be moving away from those as an anti-pattern in react. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: Related - https://github.com/yahoo/dispatchr/issues/72

That issue plus this question provided the leads I needed to get this working. Thanks!